# Distorted hyperpriors when sampling from the prior only

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, hyperparameter, pymc

I am currently testing some multilevel models in pymc3 and found that the hyperpriors get distorted when I run the level only to generate the prior. The hyperpriors I am using are generating hyperparameters for a LogitNormal distribution, but the shape of the hyperprior distributions change depending on if I include the LogitNormal or not.

Here is an example

Without LogitNormal:

```
with pm.Model() as model:
    mu = pm.Normal("mu", 0, 100)
    sd = pm.Gamma("sd", 2, 0.1)

    step = pm.Metropolis()
    trace = pm.sample(step=step, njobs=4, draws=10000,tune=1000)

pm.traceplot(trace)
pm.summary(trace)
```

With this I get a nice Normal distributed `mu` and a Gamma distributed `sd`:

[image]

Also mean, sd and RHat values all seem fine.

With the LogitNormal I have the following:

```
with pm.Model() as model:
    mu = pm.Normal("mu", 0, 100)
    sd = pm.Gamma("sd", 2, 0.1)

    v = pm.LogitNormal("v", mu=mu, sd=sd)

    step = pm.Metropolis()
    trace = pm.sample(step=step, njobs=4, draws=10000, tune=1000)

pm.traceplot(trace)
pm.summary(trace)
```

And now I get severely distorted distributions for `mu` and `sd`:

[image]

Also mean of `mu` is now at -68 and SD is at 69, so the distribution was shifted quite a lot. The RHat values do not indicate any kind of problem though. The best indication of a problem I find is that the `n_eff` of `mu` is only 247, so very low compared to the 40k samples that were generated.

If I use some other values as parameters for the hyperpriors, the problem disappears in some case. I also tried using a different step method / sampler, but this did not change anything.

Is this in any way problematic, when I use the generated variables for some model, or would this problem go away if I add some data to sample from the posterior? Also, if this can be problematic what would be the best way to diagnose and remediate such distortions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the problem is that the MCMC sampler finds it difficult to sample from the joint posterior distribution of $v$, $\mu$ and $\sigma$. This kind of problem has been [described before](http://mc-stan.org/users/documentation/case-studies/divergences_and_bias.html) for the kind of parameterization you use in case of very little data about each unit (in your case no data). You might be a lot better off, if you sampled $v'$ from $N(0,1)$ and then obtained $v$ as $v=\text{invlogit}(\mu+v'\times \sigma)$ (yes, this weird re-parameterization really helps massively in some cases, however hard it may be to believe).

By the way, it can be easier to diagnose such issues with some other MCMC samplers such as the NUTS sampler in Stan (available in python via `PyStan`). One possible hint with a standard Metropolis-Hastings would be in how the trace plots get stuck in certain regions of the posterior for a while, which one can see from the trace plots, and of course the low effective sample size is also a strong hint.

Comment: I will definitely try the methods mentioned in the link. Most importantly, the article mentions starting the sampler with different initial values to get more diagnostic RHat statistics. That also was my intuition, that the starting values somehow drive the sampler into a region where it gets stuck. Using Stan, unfortunately, is not an option for me, because my main model is coded in theano. But I found the same behavior with the NUTS sampler in pymc3.

Comment: Re-parameterizing will likely already resolve it.

Comment: If you are only looking for samples from a prior, starting in pymc3 version 3.5.0, there is a `sample_prior_predictive` function which is quite performant, since it uses a forward pass instead of MCMC. Note also that using pymc3's NUTS sampler gives a number of warnings about the inference, and suggests reparametrizing.

Comment: @Björn: Ok, tried it, reparametrization does indeed solve it. The remark about the different starting values was more to see if I can get some better diagnostics, like an increased RHat. This did not work, unfortunately, so I guess I just have to take the low effective sample size as the best diagnostic of such problems.